# Are there in guarantees about the non-aggregated columns in a GROUP BY query?

Tags: sqlite, group-by

Let's assume we have the following table and query in SQLite:

| id | val | parent | letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | a |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | b |
| 3 | 0 | 10 | c |
| 4 | 5 | 20 | d |

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(val), parent, letter FROM table GROUP BY parent
```

Are there any guarantees about the value of `id`? In MySQL there is even a mode which forbids selecting non-aggregated values. If there is no such guarantee, is it possible to somehow get a single row per `parent`?

| id | MAX(val) | parent | letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1† | 3 | 10 | a |
| 4 | 5 | 20 | d |

† or 2 (does not matter as long as `letter` is from the same row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is covered in S[ELECT/Simple Select Processing/Side note: Bare columns in an aggregate queries](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing).

In your query the columns `id` and `letter`, which are not aggregated and are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause, are called *bare* columns.
Because you use the `MAX()` aggregate function, the values of these 2 columns:

> ... take values from the input row which also contains the minimum or
> maximum

But, since there may exist more than 1 rows with the maximum `val` for the same `parent`:

> There is still an ambiguity if two or more of the input rows have the
> same minimum or maximum value

This means that for your sample data **there is no guarantee** that for `parent = 10` you will get the row with `id = 1` in the results.
You may get the row with `id = 2` which also contains the maximum `val`.

Assuming that in such a case, where for the same parent there may exist more than 1 rows with the maximum `val`, you want the row with the minimum `id`, you can do it with [window functions](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
SELECT id, val, parent, letter
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY val DESC, id) rn
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY val DESC, id) id, 
       MAX(val) OVER (PARTITION BY parent) val, 
       parent, 
       FIRST_VALUE(letter) OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY val DESC, id) letter
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2a7d90bc4bd66147395548276578c94b).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Official doc](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause)

Worth a careful read. The **bold** is what you are looking for.

> ### Aggregate Queries Can Contain Non-Aggregate Result Columns That Are
> Not In The GROUP BY Clause
>
> In most SQL implementations, output columns of an aggregate query may
> only reference aggregate functions or columns named in the GROUP BY
> clause. It does not make good sense to reference an ordinary column in
> an aggregate query because each output row might be composed from two
> or more rows in the input table(s).
>
> SQLite does not enforce this restriction. The output columns from an
> aggregate query can be arbitrary expressions that include columns not
> found in GROUP BY clause. This feature has two uses:
>
> 1. With SQLite (but not any other SQL implementation that we know of) if an aggregate query contains a single min() or max() function,
>    **then the values of columns used in the output are taken from the row where the min() or max() value was achieved. If two or more rows have
>    the same min() or max() value, then the columns values will be chosen
>    arbitrarily from one of those rows.**
>
> ...

Now, with your query

```
SELECT id, MAX(val), parent, letter FROM table GROUP BY parent
```

You basically have `id` and `letter` that are not aggregated and not in the GROUP BY.

Which means that the values returned for them are those from the row(s) matching the `MAX(val)`.

And in your case, there are 2 of them

```
id  val parent  letter
1   3   10      a
2   3   10      b
```

Which means that sqlite will **arbitrarily** (randomly) return the values of either row 1 or 2. So no, you have no guarantees.